# async in chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Is it possible to work with async/await in the chrome API's webRequest.onBeforeRequest?

The following does work; From "working" I mean it does block/cancel the request as I expect.

```js
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
  function (details) {
    console.log("URL intercepted:", {url: details.url, type: details.type,}); 
    let match = details.url.match(/:\/\/(www\.)?someSiteThatIWantAvoidRawIp\.org(\/)?$/); // you are accessing this url on your chorme 

    if (match)
    {
      console.log("URL blocked:", { url: details.url, type: details.type, match: match, });
      return { cancel: true };
    }
  },
  {
    urls: [
      "<all_urls>"
    ], 
    types: ["main_frame",]
  },
  ["blocking",]
);
```

However, the following does not work; It is supposed to block/cancel the request after waiting the await, but the cancel doesn't work but the page shows up without a connection error.

```js
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
  async function (details) {
    console.log("URL intercepted:", {url: details.url, type: details.type,}); 
    let match = details.url.match(/:\/\/(www\.)?someSiteThatIWantAvoidRawIp\.org(\/)?$/); 

    let ip = await axios.get('https://someSiteThatChecksMyIp.org', {}) // this gets my ip 
        .then(r => {
            console.log(r);
            return r.data;
        })
        .catch(e => {
            console.log(e);
        });

    if (match)
    {
        if (ip == "123.123.123.123") // assume my raw ip 
        {
            console.log("URL blocked:", { url: details.url, type: details.type, match: match, });
            return { cancel: true };
        }
    }
  },
  {
    urls: [
      "<all_urls>"
    ], 
    types: ["main_frame",]
  },
  ["blocking",]
);
```

What's incorrect with my setup? Thanks.

Comment: No, chrome extensions can't do it. The only terrible workaround is to make the network request synchronously.

Comment: Could you provide an example for that? Do you mean something like this? : ```js
axios.get('https://someSiteToCheckIp.tld', {})
      .then(r => {
        console.log(r);
        if (match)
        {
          console.log("URL blocked:", { url: details.url, type: details.type, match: match, });
          return { cancel: true };
        }
      })
      .catch(e => {
        console.log(e);
      });
``` ; I'm not a pro at JS, how can I `return` in this case? The right above works?

Comment: No. Look for examples of using "synchronous XMLHttpRequest".